# Are text Readability Scores good indicators of advanced English skills?

Tags: writing-advice, readability, story

This question is pretty subjective but will be useful for those who want to be English writers.

Basically, I wrote a short story which contains the following attributes :

- Word count: 1200
- Unique words : 452 (38%)
- Difficult Words : 438 (36%)
- Sentence count: 26
- Average Sentence Length (word) : 46.2
- Flesch Reading Ease Score: 8.2
- Flesch-Kincaid Grade Level: 23.6
- Dale-Chall Readability Index: 11.7
- Automated Readability Index: 30.4
- Coleman-Liau Index: 20.2
- Gunning Fog Index: 27
- Readability level: College graduate

What do you think of the statistics about the work that I have managed to accomplish? Do these results guarantee that I confidently possess good English skills?

I will listen to the comments and answers from real human beings to confirm that the numbers will at least mean something important to me. Of course, the story looks complicated at a glance but this does not stop the story from being interesting and enjoyable. Your thoughts will offer some insights to make me continue to refine my English skills better the next time.

As a bonus, I will showcase a part of my short story :

"*...Emrys Geijer Fremmevira declares that he will not waste his time talking to them after having confirmed that this is the exact situation they predicted it to be and their bad feelings were actually true in the first place, he commands his golden Silhouette Knight to use an ultimate attack which is so-called "Blast Howling" technique and shouts the words loudly in such an extensive way of doing, his golden Silhouette Knight begins to fortify its balance first by having a number of sticks attach to the ground to provide additional supports to the Silhouette Knight, the golden Silhouette Knight quickly opens two secret covers located on shoulder parts and two secret covers located on ankle parts to unveil a sort of mystifying weapon in the process. After swiftly accumulating the powers, four outputs release an incredible amount of plasma energy excessively towards straight the iron gate, the iron gate melts down so easily after a mere second passing by, because the extent of the super-powerful attack is so remarkable and grows more lethal and destructive the longer the entrance gate can possibly withstand the temperature and remain intact, much to all surprises for the defensive party when the iron gate is officially gone. ...*"

Some statistics about the story snippet :

- Word count: 206
- Unique Words: 133 (65%)
- Difficult Words: 75 (36%)
- Sentence count: 2
- Average Sentence Length (word) : 103
- Flesch Reading Ease Score: **-46.4**
- Flesch-Kincaid Grade Level: 45.3
- Dale-Chall Readability Index: 14.5
- Automated Readability Index: 58.4
- Coleman-Liau Index: 19.6
- Gunning Fog Index: 48.2
- Readability level: College graduate (Grade 58th student and above)

Postscript: This is the best thing I have accomplished so far. These astounding results look really intriguing, it was not easy to achieve these results at all.

Comment: xersi, would you consider re-wording your question's title? Your question is ultimately about the correlation between readability score statistics and correct English, which I think is a good question for this site. But the title makes it sound like you're soliciting personal opinions. I think your question might me downgraded unnecessarily because of the current title.

Comment: Does anyone else feel that these are very long sentences? I mean, I've written two sentences in this comment and the average sentence length is only 13.5.

Comment: @GoatsWearHats I agree, 46 words seems unusually long. It seems like a unique writing style. Come to think of it, I would actually be curious to see a sample paragraph... maybe the OP will re-appear on the post and post a sample...

Comment: The stats suggest that you have reasonably "advanced" English writing skills -- **if** you are not consciously modifying your writing to optimize the stats.  And what is "advanced" varies quite a bit between a "story" and, say, an article in *The New Yorker*.  Overly long sentences and the like can make a "story" less enjoyable.

Comment: @filistinist - I do not know a better way to rephrase the title, I will leave that to you. Thank you all, I have gotten the answers I hoped.

Comment: @filistinist - "*Come to think of it, I would actually be curious to see a sample paragraph*". Here you go, I let people see a snippet of my story.

Comment: If this question happens to receive a certain number of votes, I might as well want to let my story snippet continue to stay. I am basically aware of revision history so you know what I mean.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm really curious, what would be considered advanced writing skills? For example, I wrote the following doozy, which, according to MS Word, is perfectly grammatically correct, and is at grade level 60.5: "Mendacious, pugnaciously-vociferating, kumquat-frangipane-ingesting arthropods, perambulating widdershins, bucolic-encompassment-occupying-latrine-wise, apostrophizing delinquently-defecating pterodactyls loquaciously." Is this advanced, or ridiculously obscure?

Comment: @filistinist - You did not answer some of my questions. Utilizing the English language in an advanced way means you can express words in a variety of ways, it does not mean you have to learn the most difficult words possible. You seemed not to comprehend my question at all, filistinist.

Comment: "*Of course, the story looks complicated at a glance but this does not stop the story from being interesting and enjoyable.*"

Comment: @xersi my answer to your question is in the answer section below, I never attempted to answer in in these comments. I was asking HotLicks about their definition of advanced language use, in the abstract. Which question of yours did I miss in the answer given below?

Comment: @filistinist You should respond to my comments below your answer. Well, what is done is done, I may as well keep a piece of my work here.

Comment: @xersi sorry, but your comments are all re. lit crit or creative writing discussions. Unfortunately this is not the site for these topics and I don't want to break site policy.

Comment: @filistinist - "Advanced writing skills" means that the reader doesn't notice the writing, except perhaps for at the end thinking "Boy, that was well-written!"

Comment: The OP's sample above is pretty terrible writing, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: The fact that you wrote "which is so-called 'Blast Howling' technique" indicates that you are not as good as you'd like to be. And "attach to the ground" and "excessively towards straight the iron gate" and "the longer the iron gate can possibly withstand" and "much to all surprises for" etc

Comment: Your question, its story extract, and your various comments are sufficient evidence that your English skills are advanced for a non-native-speaker. But are you writing to improve your English or to be read with enjoyment by a wide audience? In neither case do I believe that your focus on readability statistics is helpful. In particular, your seeming desire to create ever-longer sentences is questionable. In fact, the two very long sentences of your extract are run-ons or comma splices, which most English teachers would mark as incorrect.

Comment: There is a another Stack site for writers, where you might find useful advice on how to write well: https://writers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center. It is about assessment rather than addressing particular lexical / syntactical etc usages.

Answer (score 1):

**Regaring your second question: Do these results guarantee that I confidently possess good English skills?**

My initial instinct was to say "probably yes". However, I was not sure if the methodology used by these readability grading techniques took word usage, grammar, and syntax into account. After all, someone could write long sentences with tons of grammar mistakes, and sprinkle them with complex or obscure words that are completely misused. The readability checker would have to practically be an English-speaking AI to catch all such mistakes. But I thought--maybe they have some heuristics for flagging bad grammar or word usage? So I performed the following experiment:

I tested the Flesch Reading Ease and Flesch-Kincaid Grade Level scores. To do this, I took a few paragraphs from two different texts in two foreign languages (one a short story in Russian and one a philosophy text in German, to be specific) whose grammars are conventionally considered to be relatively different from that of English. I took the "official" English translation and compared it to Google's automatic translation. Obviously the Google translation had many more mistakes in syntax and word choice. The readability scores, however, were similar for both translations.

Here is a shortened example:

**Proper sentence (by human):**

> The fact is that there no longer exists any interest either in the
>   form or the content of metaphysics or in both together. (From Hegel's
>   *Science of Logic*, [here](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/hegel/works/hl/hlprefac.htm#HL1_25))

Flesch Reading Ease Score: 54.7

Flesch-Kincaid Grade Level: 11.3

**Incorrect sentence (by Google bot):**

> This is a fact that the interest in the content, partly in the form of
>   the former metaphysics, and partly in both, is at the same time lost.
>   (translation from German version of same text as above, [here](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/wissenschaft-der-logik-1653/2))

Flesch Reading Ease Score: 66.6

Flesch-Kincaid Grade Level: 10.9

Both sentences are fairly complex, conceptually speaking. One is syntactically correct (for the most part), while the other one is mostly not. One sounds like proper English, the other one doesn't. But both have fairly similar readability scores. The second sentence actually got a slightly higher readability score, implying that it would be more comprehensible to the general reader. However, this assessment is completely misleading--the second sentence is *incomprehensible*, both grammatically and logically.

**Obviously the Flesch and Flesch-Kincaid readability scores' methods are NOT taking correct use into account. So they are NOT indicators of good vocabulary or grammar skills.**

**EDIT: I have now tested many of the other methods** using this site: http://www.readabilityformulas.com/free-readability-formula-tests.php

While I don't vouch for the accuracy of this free online tool, the results are consistent with those above. The "bad" and "good" texts score either very close, or with the "bad" text 1 to 2 grade levels below, suggesting that it is easier for the general audience to understand. Again, this is completely untrue--the "bad" text was mostly incomprehensible, at any level, due to bad grammar and word choice.

**So none of these tools are indicators of comprehensibility.** They also consistently placed text with severe grammar and logic errors at grade 9 to 11, so **they don't seem to be good at confirming language sophistication, either**. It seems that these readability scales only work as supplementary tools for a text where language proficiency is already confirmed through other means.

**As for your first question: What do you think of the statistics about the work that I have managed to accomplish?**

These scores are only approximations of reading difficulty and the educational/intellectual level your audience might need to understand your work. They are obviously not indicators of writing quality or how well your writing will be received by your target audience. I would say that a work with such low readability scores and such long sentences (26 for 1200 words?) is likely to come off as too obscure or elitist to the general reader, and would have a very limited audience. But, of course, such things are a matter of taste and convention. So ultimately, this is just my personal opinion.

Comment: Interesting. Other than *word count*, I don't think the teachers even mentioned any of those stats when I went to school. Admittedly, that was a while ago. Are these stats now common grading criteria in English classes? I don't think I've come across #5 to #10 in the OP's 11-point scheme previously.

Comment: @Lawrence, I have never heard that any of these were used as grading criteria by teachers. The word count is sometimes used to indicate how long the assignment should be, but not for actual grading of quality. The stats are available in word processing software, to give you a general idea of how simple/obscure your writing style is. In my English/Lit classes the teachers told us they're just one tool we can use to review our writing style. If the readability is too low or the grade level too high, it might be an indicator that the paper has run-ons or that it's structure might be incoherent.

Comment: Thanks! I learnt something new today. I knew that word processors had word counts and other simple stats, but I wasn't aware that they had the other scores built-in.

Comment: Note to self (and anyone else who may be interested) - [instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Test-your-document-s-readability-85b4969e-e80a-4777-8dd3-f7fc3c8b3fd2) on accessing these stats in Word.

Comment: Yeah, I am very confident in my English skills. I always endeavor to use good English grammar so this is not a problem. The real thing to achieve is that I have to make my stories look outstanding and exceptional. My stories are not intended for random people and casual readers.

Comment: @xersi your story does sound unique and like it has its own very distinct style. I, for one, am definitely fascinated and want to see more. But this site is not really for lit crit or creative writing advice, so I didn't get into it. My answer was more to the question "are the readability stats a good way to judge a text's language correctness?" And the answer seems to be no. They just don't say anything about it, one way or the other. We know YOUR English is good, we can see your post :)

Comment: I need to make my English skills fluent and exceptional, exceeding what an average American can do when it comes to the English language.

Comment: @filistinist - I wonder if that is enough for me to make money if I keep making stories like this. Is that feasible and plausible?

Comment: The answer is actually yes, readability stats are important to indicate if my stories are exceptional and outstanding enough. I like those numbers especially a person has to be a 58th-grade student to easily comprehend my particular story!

Comment: Wow, it seems like they do not want me to delete the question. All right, I will listen to the rest and what people will say so I will get the advice.
@filistinist, let me know what you think about all the things I wrote here, it seems that you are fairly new to these numbers I think. It is how a writer can maintain their amazingness of the work by paying attention to these numbers.

Comment: I feel sorry for trying to delete your efforts, but I intend to make this question more useful from now on. Writing long and rich English sentences of interesting quality is completely feasible and "**46.2** words per sentence" sounds like a pretty minor challenge for me especially when it comes to my wonderful imagination. **:)**

Comment: @xersi - How many people in the world do you think have a "58th grade" education?  You probably don't even.  The statistic is meaningless.  Try taking some text from a few of the world's best books and see what statistics you get.